# SharePoint Moderated View "My-Sub.aspx": Column header filter not displaying all options

Tags: list-view, filter

I have a SharePoint list running on SharePoint 2010. The list has about 1900 items in it and has Content Approval on.

I noticed that column header filtering in the out of the box My submissions view `(my-sub.aspx)` does not work as expected. It does not show some of the column values. For example, for a choice column with values Yes and No, it only tends to show one of the values. Another example is if I have a lookup column for e.g. with a list of countries, it does not show all the countries.

If I use an alternate view such as All Items, I can see all the column heading filter options.

Is there some limitation for the `my-sub.aspx` view?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering options never show all possibilities. They are limited to values that exist in selected view.

If you have items on the list with both `yes` and `no` values in your choice column, then you'll be able to select either of those values in *All Items* view. But if every item in *My submissions* has `yes` value selected in the column, you won't see `no` in the filters.

There is no point in filtering items by criteria that none of them meet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might not  have been very clear in my question. I do indeed see both Yes and No in the list view. however, the filter option I see only has "Yes". Hope this clarifies.